# Getting geographical coordinates in android camera

Tags: android, camera, latitude-longitude

In Android, is there any way that we can get the geographical co-ordinates when we open the camera and touch different points on the visible area?

Actually I'm finding any way to measure the length between two co-ordinates that user can see through the camera.

Please provide some easy way to do this.

Comment: or else anybody know how to do it in iOS?

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement you own camera to achieve this.

> I'm finding any way to measure the length between two co-ordinates
>   that user can see through the camera.

**Short answer NO** as,
In your custom camera in the camera parameters we set the the gps co-ordinates for a photo using this method.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setGpsLatitude(double)
Since for each photo we just set one gps data it cannot be set to multiple gps co-ordinates.If it is required we extract it through EXIF data.

> I'm finding any way to measure the length between two co-ordinates
>   that user can see through the camera.

**you can actually do this** by this way http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#metering-focus-areas
you can get the focus area as shown in the above.

> Will it solve your ISSUE

I dont know what your exact requirement is but based on the short data in your question i assume it cannot be done using the camera, however you can use the location manager to achieve this task.

Comment: Thank you so much, I will start to refer this. Actually I want to create an app for measurements such as, a building height, area of a playground, area of a building like wise. I thought when user focus the camera,, and user able to draw polygons or lines on the display according to what they need to measure. If they want to measure the height of the building, he should be able to draw a line between top of the building to the bottom then that real height should be calculated. this is what I want to do

Comment: i think you can get the measurement using photo Sphere here's the link to get you started http://www.google.com/maps/about/contribute/photosphere/   But implementing your custom camera takes a quite a bit of your effort to ensure it works across all mobiles and all screen sizes